# Is it not recommended to make back end calls from the controller in angular js

Tags: angularjs, rest

I am making a back end call to Restful service from my controller in my angular application, but my requirement states or compels me to make the back end call in the service. Why is it not recommended to make the back end calls from the controller?

Comment: Who ever down voted this question please provide some reason, why it is a bad practice, it is easy to down vote, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

from the angularjs [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller):

> Using Controllers Correctly
>   In general, a Controller shouldn't try to do too much. It should contain only the business logic needed for a single view.
>
> The most common way to keep Controllers slim is by encapsulating work that doesn't belong to controllers into services and then using these services in Controllers via dependency injection. This is discussed in the Dependency Injection and Services sections of this guide.

Answer (score 0):

Controllers should contain only the business logic.
It's a good practice to isolate the backend-call in a service, so you can use everywhere in your app, just adding the service-name into the controller.

I suggest you to read this Angular styleguide (written by John Papa and Todd Motto, two Angular guru)

It's very simple and clear

https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide